# Reproduced everything and still spider gets 302 response, manually is 200

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a site with Scrapy. Spider managed to login (I can download profile page etc). However when spider tries to access a page with data it get response with status 302 and is redirected to the main page of the site.

When I'm doing this manually with browser everything is good and browser get 200 response and page with data.

What I've done so far: 
- analysed request headers with Firebug and reproduced exactly within spider
- analysed cookies. Some of them were missing in spider because are generated by JS, added manually. So cookies are also identical.
- by deleting cookies one by one, found 1 cookie that is responsible for session login. When delete it  via firebug I got the same server behaviour as spider faces -  302 and redirect to main page. Funny thing is that this cookie is received and send by spider perfectly, according to debug info
- IP is the same (running from the same machine, spider under vagrant)

NEED HELP/ADVICE: What do i miss? Requests are very similar and server response is different What could be the reason?

Thanks in advance
 Code is

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from scrapy_test.items import Website
from scrapy.http import Request

import scrapy
import json
import time

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "mims_clean"
    custom_settings = {"DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': 400}}

    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = [
        "https://sso.mims.com"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        self.logger.info("started")
        SessionId = response.xpath('//input[@id="SessionId"]/@value').extract()[0]
        self.logger.info("SessionId is  " + SessionId)
        print("initial")
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'SignInEmailAddress': '26rqtdywe6tdg@gmail.com', 
                'SignInPassword': 'pass777',
                'SessionId' : SessionId},
            callback=self.after_login, dont_filter=True
        )
        # here everything is ok, and after login we're  redirected to profile page
        # same as in browser

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        self.logger.debug("entered after_login")
        if "error" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            print('Error found')
            return
        else:
             return Request(url="https://www.mims.com/Hongkong/Browse/Alphabet/A?cat=company",
               callback=self.after_login2, dont_filter=True)
        # we try to achieve data page 

    def after_login2(self, response):
        #but got redirected to interin tracking page
        # same as in browserreturn 
        scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            callback=self.after_login3, dont_filter=True, dont_click=True
            )
        # submit a form (in browser is done via JS)

    def after_login3(self, response):
        # got to another form with prepopulated fields (same as in browser)
        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            callback=self.after_login4, dont_filter=True, dont_click = True
            )
        return request 
        #submit the form and got to the main page with all the cookies

    def after_login4(self, response):        
        #from the main page try to go to data page
        request = Request(url="https://mims.com/Hongkong/Browse/Alphabet/A?cat=drug",
               callback=self.after_login5, dont_filter=True, headers={'Host':'mims.com',
               'Connection':'keep-alive'})   
        return request 

    def after_login5(self, response):
        # in the real bwser here I got 200 response and catalog to scrape
        # with scrapy I got 302 and get redirected to the 1st form 
        # in fact its a loop to after_login2

        #All the rest is a hopeless try to submit forms for the 2nd time :))
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            callback=self.after_login6, dont_filter=True
            )  

    def after_login6(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            callback=self.parse_final, dont_filter=True) 

    def parse_final(self, response):
        self.logger.debug("entered parse_tastypage")
        f = open('parse_final.html', 'w')
        f.write('<base href="https://sso.mims.com">')
        f.write(response.body)
        f.close()
        return
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: added code with credentials. It's possible to use them to debug in browser also

Comment: Have this in settings.py. USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0". Copied it directly from browser request via Firebug, to make request identical

Comment: I Confirm that this is happening. The login redirects make the spider not advance to the after_login3 steps. The form is there in the response but does not work inside the spider.